# difference between the typography in material/core and typography in material/system

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What's the difference between the typography in `material/core` and typography in `material/system`? Why are they from different packages? What's the difference between the two on usage?
A further question would be, I've seen two ways of using typography in material-ui for React:

1. use the typography tag like this:

   ```
   <Typography>...</Typography>
   ```
2. by defining styling constant through `createMuiTheme` with typography component:

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
     typography: {
       fontFamily: 'Raleway, Arial',
     }
   })
   ```

What's the difference between the two approaches? Is the way you implement typography related to where you imported them (`/core` or `/system`)? Which one is preferred in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they are not equivalent.

`Typography` is not equal to `typography`

---

If we want to use `<Typography />` with its full functions and props, we use **@material-ui/core**, and that's for sure the best practice in most situation.

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
```

---

**@material-ui/system** is something related with material-ui **theme**.

It's been used to export themes that can be directly applied to other components.

> @material-ui/system provides low-level utility functions called "style functions" for building powerful design systems

You can find the `typography` both in the document of default `Theme` and `System`

Refer the related document:

- MUI - [System](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/)
- MUI - [Theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/)

In my opinion, this could be a good solution to style some native or third-party libs' components with `MUI-theme` quickly. And that's the scenario when we use it.

---

#### Theme usage

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
  }
});
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>;
```

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.primary,
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();

<Typography className={classes.root} />
```

Comment: I'm new to material-ui and I would like to set up my first theme for a web project (of course it will include settings to typography). Should I go for the lower-case typography in /system to fulfill my need here? Is that what you suggest?

Comment: @Young Nope, refer to the theme document and use it as normal with normal component imported from `core` would be fine. Theme usage updated

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between the typography in material/core and typography in material/system?

The one in the core package is a **component** that you'd use to present text, similar to header and caption html elements. The one in the system package is a **function** you use when creating your own styled components. [See here for details](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/).

> Why are they from different packages?

Exports in the core package are visual components of the framework. Exports in the system package are behavioral components of the framework.

> What's the difference between the two approaches? Is the way you implement typography related to where you imported them (core or system)? Which one is preferred in practice?

No they're not related to where you import them. Use the component, unless you have a good reason not to. The second approach is for when you want to take charge and apply typography styles yourself onto a component.

Comment: Could you explain more on visual component vs behavioral component?

Comment: Sure, think of visual components as ready-to-consume exports, Material UI takes care of what makes them tick behind the scenes. If you want access to what makes them tick, well thats the behavioral components. These are the exports visual components use behind the scenes to work.

Comment: I see. Thank you @ZakDaniels99 Your answer's great too. But I only have one vote and Keikai answered first so I think I'll go with their answer.